# Terminal displaying Tamil font erronously

Tags: linux, linux-mint, terminal

Terminal not displaying Tamil font properly. How to fix this?
[image: terminal]

Comment: Are you trying to cat a file that contains Tamil or did you set your terminal language to that? Is the font in UNICODE? Does it show like this in other terminals?

Comment: It is unicode (utf-8). I was just displaying the file in the terminal. But it is the same when I try to input as well.

Comment: @SivaPrasath A screenshot seems rather appropriate when it's a terminal rendering problem

Comment: Try to install this font, https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/tamil-gtk2im

Comment: @SivaPrasath, I already have it.
`tamil-gtk2im is already the newest version`

Answer (score 0):

Even if a terminal emulator supports Unicode, it might not support rendering of complex Indic fonts like Tamil. As of today, I have only seen eshell and other shell interfaces in Emacs render Tamil text correctly. Rendering of complex Indic fonts like Tamil requires integration with additional libraries such as [m17n](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/m17n/). Installing Tamil fonts alone is not sufficient.